# Get the drop down list selected item on grid row command event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a **manage Customer** table and grid view **customer**.

I am trying to update grid record. I want when i click edit link records display in table.

I am trying to do it on **Grid_Row_command event**.

I am getting records on textbox but not able to get selected dropdown record.

Please tell me how to do this.

Here is snapshot of my table & Gridview.

[image]

.

**Here is my code-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Mspl.Web.MobileTracking.BL;
using Mspl.MobileTracking.Model;

namespace Mspl.Web.MobileTracking.UserControls
{
    public partial class ManageCustomers : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        Utility utility;
        string result = string.Empty;
        User user = new User();
        CustomerBL customerBL;
        Customer Customer = new Customer();
        CustomerBL Customers = new CustomerBL();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindCountry();
                BindCustomer();
            }

            lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void BindStates()
        {
            utility = new Utility();
            var states = utility.GetStates(ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value);
            ddlState.DataSource = states;
            ddlState.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlState.DataBind();
            ddlState.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        }

        private void BindCountry()
        {
            utility = new Utility();
            var countries = utility.GetCountries();
            ddlCountry.DataSource = countries.ToList<Country>();
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
            ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        }

        private void BindDistricts()
        {
            utility = new Utility();
            var districts = utility.GetDistricts(ddlState.SelectedItem.Value);
            ddlDistrict.DataSource = districts;
            ddlDistrict.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlDistrict.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlDistrict.DataBind();
            ddlDistrict.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
        }

        private void BindCustomer()
        {
            gvCustomer.DataSource = Customers.GetAllCustomers();
            gvCustomer.DataBind(); 
        }


        protected void gvCustomer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "displayCustomer")
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                hfCustomerId.Value = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
                Label lblCName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCustomerName");
                txtCustomerName.Text = lblCName.Text;
                Label lblAdd1 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblAddressLine1");
                txtAddressline1.Text = lblAdd1.Text;
                Label lblAdd2 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblAddressLine2");
                txtAddressline2.Text = lblAdd2.Text;
                Label lblPhone = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPhone");
                txtPhone.Text = lblPhone.Text;
                Label lblMobile = (Label)row.FindControl("lblMobile");
                txtMobileNumber.Text = lblMobile.Text;
                Label lblCountry = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCountry");
                ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblCountry.Text);
                Label lblState = (Label)row.FindControl("lblState");
                ddlState.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblState.Text);
                Label lblDistrict = (Label)row.FindControl("lblDistrict");
                ddlDistrict.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblDistrict.Text);
                Label lblCity = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCity");
                txtCity.Text = lblCity.Text; 
            }
        }

        protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindStates();
        }

        protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindDistricts();
        }

        protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customers = new Customer();
            user = Session["UserDetails"] as User;
            customers.ID = hfCustomerId.Value;
            customers.Name = txtCustomerName.Text;
            customers.Mobile = txtMobileNumber.Text;
            customers.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
            customers.AddressLine1 = txtAddressline1.Text;
            customers.AddressLine2 = txtAddressline2.Text;
            customers.Country = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Value;
            customers.State = ddlState.SelectedItem.Value;
            customers.District = ddlDistrict.SelectedItem.Value;
            customers.City = txtCity.Text;
            customers.UpdatedBy = user.ID;

            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                var result = Customers.UpdateCustomer(customers);
                if (result == "Success")
                    lblMessage.Text = "Sucessfully Updated";
                else
                    lblMessage.Text = "Already Exists";

                BindCustomer();
                refreshControls();
            }

            setFormstatus(0);

        }
    }
}
```

**My grid Code-**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
                <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
                    EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" 
                    onrowcommand="gvCustomer_RowCommand" onrowcreated="gvCustomer_RowCreated">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="normalText" BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True"
                        ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AddressLine1">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AddressLine1") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AddressLine2">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddressLine2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AddressLine2") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mobile") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="District">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDistrict" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("District") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkName" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="displayCustomer"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' >
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you are not getting values for all the drop downs? also Add you html code

Comment: Getting for ddl country only...

Comment: what values comes in your lblCountry.Text ? the Selected Country Id or the Name of the country?

Comment: getting name of the country

Comment: Have you used <%#Bind()%> for dropdownlists in your grid view ?

Comment: @folpScientist- added my grid code in question

Answer (score 0):

you have find the dropdown, fill it first with your state lists then use
like

```
ddlState.Items.FindbyText(lblState.text).Selected=true;
```

you can try like this

```
if (e.commandname == "displayCustomer") {
    GridViewRow gv = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
    label lblCountry = gv.findControl("lblCountry");
    label lblState = gv.findcontrol("lblState");
    label lblDistrict = gv.findcontrol("lblDistrict");


    //call function to fill your country


    ddlCountry.items.finbytext(lblCountry.text).selected = true;

    //call function to fill states based on ddlcountry selected item

    ddlState.items.finbytext(lblState.text).selected = true;


    //call function to fill district based on ddlStateselected item

    ddlDistrict.items.finbytext(lblDistrict.text).selected = true;



}
```

Comment: Getting error- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: first do it for country, then fill the state drop based on country  and then district based on state the it will work.

Comment: giving error on- ddlcountry.items.findbyvalue(lblcountry.text).selected=true;

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to perform all this code.

```
Label lblCountry = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCountry");
ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblCountry.Text);
Label lblState = (Label)row.FindControl("lblState");
ddlState.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblState.Text);
Label lblDistrict = (Label)row.FindControl("lblDistrict");
ddlDistrict.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(lblDistrict.Text);
```

One better way is :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkName" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="displayCustomer"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>' ></asp:LinkButton>



public void gvCustomer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here "i" is the id(CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>') of the record 
        //coming from the link button.
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        if (e.CommandName == "Edit1")
        {

            // Execute your Database query with where condition for "i" 
            // and fetch the value in data reader. The Query will be like 
            // Select * from Table_Name where ID = i
            // This will get you the particular record for that ID only

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DrpCountry.SelectedItem.Value = dr["CountryID"].ToString();
                DrpState.SelectedItem.Value = dr["StateID"].ToString();
                DrpDistrict.SelectedItem.Value = dr["DistrictID"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where I have to call this method ?

Comment: using database query to get all records, not for single one.

Comment: no just get the record for the selected row something like "select * from Table_Name where Id=i ". Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

select a particular value of drop down from

> ddlCountry.SelectedIndex=ddlCountry.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(lblCountry.Text));

Comment: Getting record for country, not getting for state and district.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

The problem is, when you select the value in your Country `DropDown`, it is already filled, while your State and City `DropDown`s are NOT filled that is why they are NOT working,

```
    protected void gvCustomer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "displayCustomer")
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            hfCustomerId.Value = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
            Label lblCName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCustomerName");
            txtCustomerName.Text = lblCName.Text;
            Label lblAdd1 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblAddressLine1");
            txtAddressline1.Text = lblAdd1.Text;
            Label lblAdd2 = (Label)row.FindControl("lblAddressLine2");
            txtAddressline2.Text = lblAdd2.Text;
            Label lblPhone = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPhone");
            txtPhone.Text = lblPhone.Text;
            Label lblMobile = (Label)row.FindControl("lblMobile");
            txtMobileNumber.Text = lblMobile.Text;
            Label lblCountry = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCountry");


            // -------------------------- changed code --------------------------

            ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = ddlCountry.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(lblCountry.Text))


            // at this point country should be filled and selected, so we can bind and select appropriate state
            BindStates();

            Label lblState = (Label)row.FindControl("lblState");
            ddlSate.SelectedIndex = ddlSate.Items.IndexOf(ddlSate.Items.FindByText(lblState.Text))

            // at this point states should be filled and selected, so we can bind and select appropriate District
            BindDistricts();


            Label lblDistrict = (Label)row.FindControl("lblDistrict");
            ddlDistrict.SelectedIndex = ddlDistrict.Items.IndexOf(ddlDistrict.Items.FindByText(lblDistrict.Text))

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------

            Label lblCity = (Label)row.FindControl("lblCity");
            txtCity.Text = lblCity.Text; 
        }
    }
```

As you have mentioned in you comments that `Country` column in `GridView` is actually Country Name NOT Country ID. While you are converting this `lblCountry.Text` into `int32` and trying set the index. This should give the error I suppose.

The approach you have currently adopted does NOT seem to right, a better approach may be is to save the ID of the record in the Grid in some `HiddenField` for example, and on `RowCommand`, pick the ID from `HiddenField`, get the data from Database and then load in your input boxes.

Anyway for a workaround, save the `CountryID` along with your Country Name in a `HiddenField`,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCountryID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("CountryID") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you can set the `DropDown` using this `CountryID`

```
var hfCountryID = row.FindControl("hfCountryID") as HiddenField;
ddlCountry.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(hfCountryID.Text);
```

Another workaround can be to find the Item using Country Name and select it,

```
ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = ddlCountry.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(lblCountry.Text));
```

Comment: Don't have a country id field in database.

Comment: Then you can go with Country Name option

Comment: i am getting value in country, not getting in state and district.

Comment: You have to do the Binding in start... currently you are NOT doing Binding for State and District

Comment: I am binding state and district on selected index

Comment: Getiing this error--- The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to create a function that get the ID of the country or state or whatever 
then you can do :

```
ddlCounty.SelectedValue=CountyID.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = ddlCountry.Items.IndexOf
(ddlCountry.Items.FindByText(lblCountry.Text);
```

Comment: what is Status here ?

Comment: Then try this ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = lblCountry.Text;

Comment: i am getting selected index for country, not getting for state and district.

Comment: which method you try ?